# CentOS and a small boost example

Tags: centos, gcc, c++, boost

I ask this question here, because I think, it has more to do with linux than with boost itself.

So i created a small cpp file:

```
#include <boost/math/special_functions/round.hpp>
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    std::cout << "Start rounding ..." << std::endl;

    double b = boost::math::round(1.5);
    std::cout << "Rounding of 1.5: " << b << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Now I started to compile it:

```
g++ main.cpp
```

Everythink worked and I got a `a.out` file. When I type the command `ldd a.out`, I get this:

```
linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffdfdf38000)
libstdc++.so.6 => /lib64/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f6183d77000)
libm.so.6 => /lib64/libm.so.6 (0x00007f6183a74000)
libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib64/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f618385e000)
libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007f618349d000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f61840a7000)
```

I got a question here:

Why there is no error when compiling? I would assume, that the compiler / linker say: `Hey, there is a function declared (in the boost hpp file), but not defined.` I assumed, that the definition of the round function is defined in one of the boost libraries. And I assumed, that I should add to the compilation / linking process something like `-lboost_math_c99l`.

Comment: See [Header-Only Libraries](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/more/getting_started/unix-variants.html#header-only-libraries) in the boost [Getting Started on Unix Variants](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/more/getting_started/unix-variants.html) documentation.

Comment: @steeldriver: Your comment is the answer ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Hmm, failed for me (on Mac OS X) so let's see where CentOS might be getting that file from...

```
# yum whatprovides '*/round.hpp'
...
```

and somewhere in that output there should be references to `boost-devel` of some architectural vintage. So I'd assume your system has the `boost-devel` package installed, which includes the desired header, which the compiler can thus find (unless the build environment is borked). Knowing the package name, you can dig around in that:

```
# rpm -ql boost-devel | grep ns/round.hpp
/usr/include/boost/math/special_functions/round.hpp
```